# How can I get numbers after certain words?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a variable with a few words each followed by a number, how can I get certain number that came after one certain word?

For example if I have:

```
var a = "books23 birds47 cars38";
```

How can I get the number 47 by looking at the word "birds"? To be more clear, how can I get the number that comes after "birds"?

Comment: Use `/birds(\d+)/`

Comment: @anubhava: You should post it as the answer here.

Comment: Just a regex demo for @anubhava's expression: https://regex101.com/r/pE2wP0/1

Comment: Didn't post as answer as I thought it would be duplicate of some other post that I could not find :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution which conveniently stores the matches in the object:

```js
var a = "books23 birds47 cars38";
var things = {};
a.split` `.map(function(x){
  things[x.match(/[a-z]+/g)[0]] = x.match(/[0-9]+/g)[0];
})
console.log(things.books);
console.log(things.birds);
console.log(things.cars);
```

Comment: Very nice and organized, I like this.

Comment: @Ogdila Welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
var nums = a.split(' ').map(function(b) {
  return b.match(/[0-9]+/g)[0];
});
```

now those nums are actually strings, if you want them to be numbers do this:

```
var numbers = nums.map(Number);
```

quick demo: https://jsbin.com/mugime/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 1):

"After one certain word" - if it's a fixed word, you can use a regular expression containing the word itself:

```
var num = /birds(\d+)/.exec(a)[1];
```

The `[1]` tells it to extract the group `(\d+)` which means a string of one or more digits.

This will also match things like `bigbirds47` though. You can use `\b` to specify that it must be on a word boundary:

```
var num = /\bbirds(\d+)/.exec(a)[1];
```

If you want it to work for other words, you can build a regex pattern from a string like this:

```
var word = "birds";
var num = new RegExp("\\b"+word+"(\\d+)").exec(a)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tricky function to collect all name:value pairs from your string.

```
function cnt(str){
  var a = {};//empty object
  str.replace(/\b(\D+)(\d+)/ig, 
              function(m, nm, val){
                //m - whole match
                //nm is (\D+), val is (\d+)
                // \d - digits 0 - 9, \D - non-digits, \b - word boundary 
                a[nm] = a[nm] || [];//in case there are cars38 and cars125
                a[nm].push(val);
                return m;// do not change str
              });
  return a;
}

var a = cnt("books23 birds47 cars38 cars125");
console.log(a); // Object { books:["23"], birds:["47"], cars:["38", "125"]}
```